# Why does Fluorine react differently than other halogens during Hydrohalogenation/Halogenation and also substitution with Alkanes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halogenation

From what I understand, during halogenation with an alkene or alkyne, diatomic gaseous halogen molecules can effectively 'break' the pi bond to produce a haloalkane/haloalkene. However I discovered that Fluorine cannot undergo this reaction, as it produces different products. I'm not so interested in what the other reaction is and products are produced, but more WHY the fluorine reaction is different to that of Chlorine, Bromine, and Iodine. I suspect it is due to Fluorine's extremely high electronegativity?

Furthermore, during a substitution reaction with alkanes and a halogen to produce a haloalkane and hydrogen halide as a byproduct, often catalysed by UV light, why does Fluorine react explosively in this case, whilst Iodine is generally unreactive? Is this also because of electronegativity?

Comment: Sulfur and selenium are also more similar than oxygen and sulfur, same for lithium, sodium and potassium.

Comment: The F-F bond is weak making the generation of F. radicals an easy process, but the C-F bond is very strong making the process highly energetically favourable and exothermic.